# compose email in outlook with attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, c#-4.0, email-client

In my application, I have a requirement where if a user clicks on invoice number the generated invoice statesment is attached to a composed email in outlook. Using code below i am able to send automated emails but i need to just compose and open the outlook window for user to review and edit the contents. Do not send. Kindly help.

```
public void pdfStatement(string InvoiceNumber)

 {

     InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber.Trim();
     string mailServer = "server";
     string fileName = InvoiceNumber;
     string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/reports/");
     string messageBody = "Its an automated test email, please ignore if you receive this.";
     CreateMessageWithAttachment(mailServer, filePath, fileName, messageBody);
 }


  public void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string mailServer, string filePath, string fileName, string messageBody)

      {

     MailMessage message = new MailMessage (
                                            "user@domain.com",
                                            "user@domain.com",
                                            "TestEmail",
                                             messageBody);

      filePath = filePath + fileName + ".pdf";

     // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
     Attachment attach = new Attachment(filePath);
     attach.Name = fileName + ".pdf";
     // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
     message.Attachments.Add(attach);
     //Send the message. 
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
     var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
     client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
     client.Send(message);
 }
```

Comment: The link that he sent you below will work, even if you don't send you could add a RTF control or a Memo / edit box control that will let you view / preview the contents.. sounds like before even sending out the email you need some sort of validation process stubbed in prior to sending the email.. otherwise why do you attempt to generate the email when they click on it..  another thing you may consider is adding a js alert if it's a web app or a msgDialog if it's a windows app asking if they want to preview the contents. and after preview allow them to either canecl or send..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this will help but how about u just create a form in tha page and allow user to type/see what they be sending. 
[Sample here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/10/send-email-with-attachment-in-aspnet.html)

Also Preview button can help

EDIT:
Then u need to use  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace to create a mail item.
[First sample here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/165548/C-Code-snippet-to-send-an-Email-with-attachment-fr)
From the sample, the MailItem class(oMsg) also has a Display() Method which should display the created email.
[Second sample (ASP.NET version)](http://w3mentor.com/learn/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/c-interoperability/sending-mail-using-outlook-in-c-asp-net/)

Comment: hv got a documented requirment, can not change it. Have edit the question to be more clear

Comment: try using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. see my EDIT