# Python: Open outlook compose instance with attachments

Tags: python, python-2.7, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I know that this exist: [compose email in outlook with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449641/compose-email-in-outlook-with-attachment) - but it's not python.

I want to use python to open an Outlook compose instance with some files attached and recipients in To and CC fields (an perhaps had some text in the message). The user should then be able to write in the message and press send.

I was thinking that win32com might do it, but haven't found some examples.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inspired by @Timo I found the following solution to work for me.

```
import subprocess
outlookpath2doc = '"C:/Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"'
compose = '/c ipm.note'
recipients = '/m "recipient@example.com; recipient2@example.com&subject=Please take a look at this"'
attachment = '/a "' + path2doc + '"'
command = ' '.join([outlookpath2doc, compose, recipients, attachment])
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use command line arguments to start Outlook:

```
outlook /a "C:\path\to\attachment" /c ipm.note /m "recipient@example.com; recipient2@example.com"
```

In python, just use [`os.system(command)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=startfile#os.system) to open outlook with your switches.

You can see all available switches [on the Microsoft website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx).

Comment: You have to approve the edited version I made of your post with `subprocess` in order for me to approve it as the solution.

Comment: If what I answered didn't work for you, then don't accept it. Your edit changes much of my answer, so you should either comment on my answer or add a new answer and accept that one.